# MCMC in tensorflow regression problem (microlensing light curve)

Tags: tensorflow2.0, bayesian, mcmc

I am stuck on a problem of fitting a function in tensorflow, precisely a microlensing light curve in the field of gravitational lensing. I have already performed the fit but I need to estimate the errors of the parameters [flux, t0, y0, tE] and other statistical properties of the parameters. I tried to perform a MCMC with tensorflow probability but I am not obtaining what I need and I cannot find the code/conceptual errors. Also can someone explain how to visualize the results: 2d maps of confidence intervals and corner plot? Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance!

Imports:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('white')
from astropy import constants as const

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

G = tf.constant(const.G.value, dtype=tf.float32)
c = tf.constant(const.c.value, dtype=tf.float32)
msun = tf.constant(const.M_sun.value, dtype=tf.float32)
rad2arcsec = tf.constant(np.rad2deg(1.0) * 3600.0, dtype=tf.float32) # arcsec per radian
```

Functions to compute magnification:

```
def einstein_radius(mass, ds, dl):
    """
    Einstein radius of a point lens [arcsec]
    """
    A = (4.0 * G * mass * msun / c**2) * (1.0 / 3.0857e+19) # in kpc
    dist_module = (ds - dl) / (ds * dl) 
    return tf.sqrt(A * dist_module) * rad2arcsec
    

def einstein_crosstime(mass, ds, dl, vel):
    """
    Einstein crossing time [days]
    """
    theta_E = einstein_radius(mass, ds, dl)
    tE = (dl * (theta_E / rad2arcsec) * 3.0857e+16) / vel # in seconds
    return tE / (24.0 * 3600.0) # in days
    

def magnification(t, flux, t0, y0, tE):
    """
    Magnification of a point source due to a point lens
    """
    y1 = (t - t0) / tE
    y2 = tf.ones_like(t) * y0
    yy = tf.sqrt(y1**2 + y2**2)
    mu = flux * (yy**2 + 2.0) / (yy * tf.sqrt(yy**2 + 4.0))
    return mu
```

Array of x (time) and y (magnification) and parameters:

```
t = tf.constant(np.arange(0, 365), dtype=tf.float32)
params_source = {
    'flux': tf.constant(10.0, dtype=tf.float32), # counts
    'ds': tf.constant(9.0, dtype=tf.float32), # kpc
    'vel': tf.constant(210.0, dtype=tf.float32) # km/s
}

params_lens = {
    'mass': tf.constant(0.2, dtype=tf.float32), # M_sun
    'dl': tf.constant(6.0, dtype=tf.float32), # kpc
    't0': tf.constant(183.0, dtype=tf.float32), # days
    'y0': tf.constant(0.5, dtype=tf.float32) # arcsec
}
tE = einstein_crosstime(params_lens['mass'], params_source['ds'], params_lens['dl'], params_source['vel'])
mu_ = magnification(t, params_source['flux'], params_lens['t0'], params_lens['y0'], tE)
noise = tf.random.normal(mu_.shape, mean=0.0, stddev=0.1, dtype=tf.float32)
mu = mu_ + noise
```

MCMC:

```
# Bayesian inference with MCMC with tensorflow_probability
mu_obs = mu

# Prior distributions
flux_prior = tfp.distributions.Uniform(low=0.1, high=50.0)
t0_prior = tfp.distributions.Uniform(low=0.1, high=365.0)
y0_prior = tfp.distributions.Uniform(low=0.1, high=1.0)
tE_prior = tfp.distributions.Uniform(low=0.1, high=183.0)

def joint_log_prob(flux, t0, y0, tE):
    prior = flux_prior.log_prob(flux) + t0_prior.log_prob(t0) + y0_prior.log_prob(y0) + tE_prior.log_prob(tE)
    
    mu_predicted = magnification(t, flux_prior.sample(), t0_prior.sample(), y0_prior.sample(), tE_prior.sample())
    likelihood = tf.reduce_sum(tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=mu_predicted, scale=0.1).log_prob(mu))
    return prior + likelihood

unnormalized_posterior = lambda *args: joint_log_prob(*args)

num_results = 1000
num_burnin_steps = 200

# Run Hamiltonian Monte Carlo
hmc_kernel = tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
    target_log_prob_fn=unnormalized_posterior,
    num_leapfrog_steps=3,
    step_size=1.0
)

adaptive_hmc = tfp.mcmc.SimpleStepSizeAdaptation(
    inner_kernel = hmc_kernel,
    num_adaptation_steps=int(num_burnin_steps * 0.8)
)

@tf.function
def run_chain():
    samples, is_accepted = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
        num_results=num_results,
        num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
        current_state=[params_source['flux'], params_lens['t0'], params_lens['y0'], tE],
        kernel=adaptive_hmc,
        trace_fn=lambda _, pkr: pkr.inner_results.is_accepted,
        parallel_iterations=10
        )
    return samples

num_chains = 100
chains = [run_chain() for _ in range(num_chains)]
```